# Popup-шаблон уничтожается при закрытии. Как предотвратить его уничтожение?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

В popup находится фильтр. При закрытия popup он уничтожается из html и все установленные фильтры не отображаются при повторном открытии. Фильтр используется WBW Product Filter.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.